# How to use RoboPOJOGenerator to automatically generate model class from Json in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, code-generation

I will share a way to generate class from Json in Android.

> **Generate Java and Kotlin POJO files from JSON: GSON, AutoValue, Logan Square, FastJSON, Jackson, Moshi, empty annotations template. Supports: primitive types, multiple inner JSONArrays.**

This is a demo:

[image]

You can download it from :
**"Preferences" -> "Plugins" -> "Browse Repositories" -> "RoboPOJOGenerator"**[image]

And how to use:

[image]

And you paste you json to popup and choose parser type:

[image]

And click generate, it will gen class from json for you!

[image]

I hope it can help you to save many time!

Comment: If you have other tips to reduce your work time, please share with us. Thank you!

Comment: Technically this should be an answer to a question (you can ask and answer your own question) and your second screenshot isn't highlighting the plug-in you are advocating.

Comment: OK, thank you, i edited image with new image.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I will second this...

Comment: [This question is being discussed in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375886/is-it-possible-to-re-open-this-question-just-so-that-we-can-move-the-question)

Comment: Nice job! thx for sharing